# copy array of cells if value equals 1

Tags: excel

[image]i am looking at cells A2:A201 for a value of 1. create an array list of all items that contain a 1 with the contents of cell E and B of each row.

the way i am currently using is not really a clean version so im looking to simplify

```
=INDEX(tbl,SMALL(IF((INDEX(tbl,,12,1)<=1)*(INDEX(tbl,,12,1)>=1),ROW(tbl)-MIN(ROW(tbl))+1,""),ROWS($T$14:T14)),,1)
```

while that works, i am trying to simplify and make it look better to use more often without creating multiple tables.

also, i am using the above to also get the positions (cell e) of players (cell b). the output is scrambled order so i would really love to put them in order for sports. PG Name, PG Name, SG Name, SG name, SF name, SF Name, etc etc.

Comment: Somehow your formula does not fit at all to the words of your question. Are you sure you pasted the correct formula? What does `tbl` reference? And how does cell e or cell b come in? Not even wondering about PG Name etc.

Comment: i took the formula i posted as an example of what i was  using for another sheet which has same data just in different columns. in that formula, its looking in column 12 or L for value of 1. i moved that datato a new excel in A column. i used another of that formula. tbl is in reference to the whole data to look up because like i said im trying to simplify it.

Comment: The [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) takes three parameters. What does `INDEX(tbl,,12,1)` do?

Comment: that's the reference flavor of Index, which has an optional 4th parameter: Area_num  Optional. Selects a range in reference from which to return the intersection of row_num and column_num. The first area selected or entered is numbered 1, the second is 2, and so on. If area_num is omitted, INDEX uses area 1.

Comment: @teylyn - Thanks heaps! I never use that parameter in this context and was worried that the OP was misusing it when slicing off a column.

Comment: @Jeeped - you and me, we've used the reference flavour of Index() a million times. But I've never, ever actually used the area parameter. It DOES look intriguing, but I think most common users' data sets are not suitable. I'll keep an eye out for use cases. Let me know if you find something useful. You know where to find me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to visually simplify the formula the single biggest portion that can be eliminated is `ROW(tbl)-MIN(ROW(tbl))+1`. This produces the *position within* **tbl** and not the actual row on the worksheet. By starting **tbl** in the second row, you have to make this calculation. If you simply started **tbl** at row 1, then this becomes `ROW(tbl)` because the *rows within* **tbl** will always match the rows on the worksheet and do not have to be adjusted due to a different starting position.

In order to get the second, third, etc match from the column of ones and blanks, you need to provide cyclic calculation. Whether you use an array formula or a function that provides array-like calculation, you will want to but down the number of rows processed to the minimum required for processing.

You could do this with a named range (e.g. `tbl`) and then you have to slice off columns for individual column lookups. You also have to maintain and resize `tbl` if the data changes. This can be avoided by defining **tbl** with a formula that reduces the rows to the last number found in column A.

```
=Sheet1!$A$1:INDEX(Sheet1!$E:$E, MATCH(1e99, Sheet1!$A:$A))
```

When dealing with columns within **tbl**, you can 'slice' off a column using the [INDEX function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a). Leave the *row_num* blank (or **0**) to indicate all rows and provide the *column_num* you want to deal with.

[image: TBL_INDEX]

The newer [AGGREGATE¹ function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) can make quick work of retrieving the first, second, third, etc. matches to one or more columns. Use the [SMALL sub-function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SMALL-function-4050a82e-659a-4ef6-a970-c963a6f69c29) (i.e. **15**) and force and non-matches into a `$DIV/0!` error state while using the **6** option to ignore errors.

Sorting the data 'on-the-fly' during retrieval is marginally possible but the better solutions involve a 'helper' column.

---

¹ <sub>The [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) was introduced with Excel 2010. It is not available in earlier versions.</sub>